# Upgrading from 14.04.05 LTS to 16.04.02 LTS fails

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS to 16.04.2 LTS but keep getting 404 errors for certain files. I had already run sudo-apt-get update OK, as well as apt-get dist-upgrade OK. I also tried running sudo apt-get clean but no change...

After typing sudo do-release-upgrade, the upgrade process chugs away for a while, then I'll see the following:
...

```
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe Sources
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe i386 Packages
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe Sources
404  Not found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe i386 Packages
404  Not found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe Sources
```

...

```
Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of
network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

W:Failed to fetch
http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/sources/Sources
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.

Restoring original system state
```

...

Now, if I go to a web browser and paste in the address above, I do get the 404 error. I have to go to /ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/source before I can get a directory listing.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!
Sir_Timbit

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks... But looking at that site, the directory structure appears to be the same as ca.archive.ubuntu.com. So if I browse http://muug.ca/mirror/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/sources/Sources, I get the 404 error again...